# How to register a signal handler for a subprocess?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, signals

Adding a signal handler, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess as sp
import signal
import time

def child_handler(sig, frame):
    print("SIGINT child received")

def handler(sig, frame):
    print("SIGINT received")

def preexec():
    print("entering preexec")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, child_handler)
    #signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)
    print("leaving preexec")

def signal_sending():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)
    p = sp.check_call(["bash", "process.sh"], preexec_fn=preexec)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal_sending()
```

with `process.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

i=0

while [ 1 ]; do
sleep 0.1;
echo $i
i=$((i + 1))
done
```

doesn't work because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> interrupts the child process (only `SIGINT received` is printed), but both `SIGINT received` and `SIGINT child received` should be printed and the child continue to run.

Adding `signal.SIG_IGN` leaves the child untouched, but that not sufficient since I need to write a custom handler for the child.

I don't care if I have to use python 2.7 or 3.x to acchieve that. I'm using Linux 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bash` process replaces the forked `python` process and therefore it can't run a Python callback. `SIG_IGN` works for `SIGINT` because it survives the `exec()` call.

If you want some Python code to run when <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> is pressed; put it in the `handler()` (the signal handler in the parent). Or trap the corresponding signal in bash and run python subprocess on the signal in `process.sh`.

Comment: Ahh, I just requested better docs on signal handling at http://bugs.python.org/issue25787. Any idea how to prevent reception of SIGINT of subprocesses of subprocesses? I'm struggeling with `apt-get` which spawns `dpkg` which itself spawns processes like `gpgv` and aborts because SIGINT is received by children of child.

Comment: Ctrl+C in the shell sends SIGINT to all processes in the foreground process group (the current pipeline). Pass `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` to create a new process group, to avoid propagating the signal to the subprocess (and its descendants).

Comment: Specifying `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` causes the terminal (`gnome-terminal` and `xterm`) to become unresponsive expect for `SIGINT` which is handled in the parent process (in my registered custom handler).

Comment: @KarlRichter: the point of `preexec_fn=os.setpgrp` is so that some signals in the shell won't be propagated to the child processes that otherwise would (and therefore the children won't be killed by these signals). It is what you've wanted: *"prevent reception of SIGINT [on Ctrl+C] of subprocesses of subprocesses"*.  `os.setpgrp` doesn't create the unreponsiveness issue, it may expose it if it exists already: if a child process may stuck then if you remove the ability to kill it from the shell directly [on Ctrl+C]; it appears unresponsive. If it is still unclear; ask a separate question